# How to enable docker-proxy

Tags: linux, docker, unix

I am trying to install a docker package following [this instruction](https://hub.docker.com/r/epgg/eg/).

The command I tried to run is as follow:

```
$ docker pull epgg/eg
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/epgg/eg ...
sha256:33a547c7e2d62e4dbaa8b27a3f63145fde5f3a3cde1719e17f8299b6e1fb01b3: Pulling from docker.io/epgg/eg
Digest: sha256:33a547c7e2d62e4dbaa8b27a3f63145fde5f3a3cde1719e17f8299b6e1fb01b3
Status: Image is up to date for docker.io/epgg/eg:latest
```

Then:

```
$ docker run -p 80:80 --name eg -it epgg/eg bash
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint eg 
(1882e9fb408e59b92b64d5be9aa8dcecd2b8c6606a89d0771274cfbc25aa6f4a): exec: 
"docker-proxy": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

As you can see it is asking for 'docker-proxy'. How can I enable that?
I can't find that executable in my system.

Comment: Docker-proxy will be needed while you are applying -p flag in docker run. Docker-proxy is a executable file after docker engine installation, just like dockerd. So maybe you should try it with root, or chmod for all executable files of docker. There is no other concerns.

Comment: Sounds like a broken install. Uninstall docker and reinstall, verifying you are using the official docker provided repos for your packages.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to reinstall docker.

See https://discuss.gogs.io/t/solved-docker-container-complains-with-docker-proxy-executable-not-found-in-path/1675

> I was able to solve the issue by removing the Rackspace repo I installed docker from, and followed the guide for installing docker CE from the following official link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/

Comment: I got the same error as OP on a fresh, up-to-date CentOS 7 where Docker was installed as `yum install docker`.  As proposed in this answer, uninstall that and re-installing the Docker CE, running `docker pull ...` to refresh, and things work.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
ln -sf /usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current /usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy
```

Answer (score -2):

Steps:

1. `$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
2. Create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable:

`[Service] Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"`.

Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server, create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf` that adds the `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable:

`[Service] Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"`

3. `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
4. `$ sudo systemctl restart docker`
5. Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

`$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/`

For https:
`$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/`

Follow above commands 
source: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Comment: This looks like a solution to a completely different problem. The docker-proxy for publishing ports has nothing to do with an http proxy to access the internet.

Comment: I think he changed the question, can you check the question history. My question was upvoted before but now question is edited.

Comment: I do not see any edit record on this question, it appears to be the same as they originally asked.

Comment: May be there is a bug